# Generate a list using list comprehension in Python which gives the count of numbers and put the number at the specific index

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose I have a list

```
input = [4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
```

This list can contain (repeating) numbers from 0 to n (here n=4).
Can I generate a list using list comprehension, where the value at index is equal to the count of that number in list a
For e.g., output list in above scenario would be

```
output = [0, 2, 7, 4, 2]
```

Explanation

```
here
output[0] = 0 #since we don't have any 0 in input list
output[1] = 2 #since we have two 1's in input list
output[2] = 7 #since we have seven 2's in input list
output[3] = 4 #since we have four 3's in input list
output[4] = 2 #since we have two 4's in input list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

inp = [4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]

c = Counter(inp)
output = [c[k] for k in range(max(c)+1)]
```

*NB. do not use `input` as a variable name, this is a python builtin*

output:

```
[0, 2, 7, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Could even use `operator.itemgetter(*range(max(c)+1))(c)`

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
[d.setdefault(el, []).append(1) for el in input]
[len(d.get(k, [])) for k in range(max(d.keys()) + 1)]
# [0, 2, 7, 4, 2])
```